# Jenkins SSL certificate from Windows AD CS

Tags: ssl, jenkins, certificate, keytool, mmc

I am trying to configure Jenkins on Windows with a SLL certificate following [these instructions](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins). Instead of using a Digicert certificate, our IT administrator would like to generate a certificate using the Windows AD CS using the certificate snap-in of mmc.
However we cannot figure out how to import the keytool generated csr certificate request into the certificate snap-in.
If I use a certificate with a recreated certificate request in the mmc certificate store, the certificate is rejected with the following message:

```
keytool -importcert -alias jenkins -file "D:\Temp\jenkins\jenkins.pem" -keystore "D:\Temp\jenkins\jenkins.jks"
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate reply does not contain public key for <jenkins>
```

Does anyone know how to create an SSL certificate from the Windows certificate store based on a java keytool created csr certificate request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get Jenkins running with SSL and this is what I did.

**On the Jenkins Master**

1. In the Certificate Snap-in of mmc, navigate to Certificates (Local
   Computer) / Personal.
2. Right click Personal Folder and select All Tasks / Request New
   Certificate...
3. Confirm the next two Enrollment pages by clicking on Next.
4. Check a Webserver Active Directory Enrollment Policy.
5. A Warning Message shows below the Enrollment Policy

   > More information is required to enroll for this certificate. Click here
   >   to configure settings.

   Click on it.
6. Fill out the Certificate Properties:
    Subject name: Common name:
   [the name of your jenkins server]
    Alternative name: DNS: [the
   name of your jenkins server]
    Alternative name: DNS: [the full
   name of your jenkins server including your domain]
   Confirm the
   page with OK and the following two pages.
7. Export the Certificate as PFX format
    Right click on
   certificate
    All Tasks / Export...
8. Check: Yes, export the private key
    Check Include all
   certificates in the certification path if possible
    Check:
   Export all extended properties
    Since we are exporting the
   private key, we must provide a password
    Check: Password and
   enter your password and password confirmation
9. Pick a path for your PFX certificate and finish the export.
10. Export the certificate one more time without a password in the
     Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER) format.
11. Rename the resulting .CER file into .PEM.
12. Create a java key store on the Jenkins server with

    ```
    keytool -genkeypair -keysize 2048 -keyalg RSA -alias jenkins -keystore jenkins.jks
    ```
13. Answer the questions appropriate for your company and organisation.
14. Import the PFX certificate into the java keystore with

    ```
    keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jenkins.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore jenkins.jks -deststoretype JKS
    ```
15. Copy the `jenkins.jks` to secrets directory where Jenkins is
     installed (in my case `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets`).
16. Add the certificate to the Jenkins startup parameters:

    ```
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%JENKINS_HOME%\secrets\jenkins.jks
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=[your password for the java key store]
    ```
17. Restart the jenkins service

**On the Jenkins Agent**

18. Import the PEM certificate from above into the java keystore from the command line with administrator priviliges:

    ```
    keytool -import -alias jenkins -keystore "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\security\cacerts" -file [your pem file]
    ```

    Enter the password of the keystore (by
     default     changeit)
     Trust  this certificate? [no]: yes
19. Make sure your `jenkins-slave.xml` in `%JENKINS_HOME%` does not contain
    `-noCheckCertificate` in the arguments.
20. Restart the service `jenkinsslave-D__Jenkins`.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading the [tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) you have mentioned in your post. And I see this sentence:
"if making your own certificate skip steps 3, 4, and 5". Your code seems to be the specified in step 5.

You could try to copy the keystore file to your Jenkins secrets directory as mentioned in step 6.

[This link](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO346&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1462472658541) can also be helpful.

Comment: I can skip steps 3, 4 and 5. I can copy the keystore file to jenkins secrets. Jenkins does start up and does not complain about SSL issues. But when I navigate to the jenkins website with https:\\jenkins the browser warns of a not secure connection.
To avoid the warning and to allow AD logins are the main reasons for running jenkins with SSL.

Comment: Have you read this article? https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203821254-How-to-install-a-new-SSL-certificate-